# How to Fix the Issue Where the Page Does Not Load When Clicking a Button

Tags: javascript, java, spring, security, thymeleaf

***Overview***

After a successful login, you are redirected to the index page.

On the index page, there is a button labeled "Test Button". When clicked, it is supposed to call an API that loads the "test" page.

However, only the API request is made, and the page does not change.

The developer tools only display the HTML code of that page.

> index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Logout button event
    $('#logoutButton').click(function() {
        // Remove token from local storage
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
        // Redirect to login page
        window.location.href = '/login';
    });

    // Test button event
    $('#testButton').click(function() {
        // Retrieve token from local storage
        const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        if (token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/test', // URL of the server to request
                type: 'GET', // HTTP method
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    // Add token to request header
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // Logic on request success
                    console.log("Test request successful:", data);
                    alert("Test request successful");
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Logic on request failure
                    console.error("Test request failed:", xhr.responseText);
                    alert("Test request failed");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Token not found. Please login again.");
        }
    });
});
```

As shown, the token is fetched from local storage and subsequently reattached to the request header for transmission.

**JwtAuthorizationFilter**

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Extract token from header
        log.info("Extracting token from header");
        String tokenValue = jwtUtil.getJwtFromHeader(req);
        log.info("Token: " + tokenValue);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(tokenValue)) {

            // Token validation
            if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(tokenValue)) {
                log.info("Token Error");

                return;
            }
            Claims info = jwtUtil.getUserInfoFromToken(tokenValue);

            try {
                setAuthentication(info.getSubject());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        }

        else {
            log.info("No token present.");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    // Process authentication
    public void setAuthentication(String loginId) {
        log.info("Authentication successful");
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        Authentication authentication = createAuthentication(loginId);
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
    }

    // Create authentication object
    private Authentication createAuthentication(String loginId) {
        log.info("Creating authentication object");
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(loginId);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }
```

When the JwtAuthorizationFilter is in place, the logs display the entire process of extracting the token from the header, and I've confirmed that the authentication object is also successfully created.

**Console**

```
2024-02-26T15:01:04.238+09:00  INFO 60005 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] JWT Verification and Authorization       : Token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0NiIsImF1dGgiOiJPV05FUiIsImlhdCI6MTcwODkyNDY0NiwiZXhwIjoxNzA4OTI4MjQ2fQ.TLjHCc1_ZtTbzGb-2c0ueLmxgCyxQf1rUQs4DkqMv_c
    2024-02-26T15:01:04.259+09:00  INFO 60005 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] JWT Verification and Authorization       : Authentication successful
    2024-02-26T15:01:04.259+09:00  INFO 60005 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] JWT Verification and Authorization       : Creating authentication object
    Hibernate: 
        /* <criteria> */ select
            u1_0.id,
            u1_0.email,
            u1_0.login_id,
            u1_0.password,
            u1_0.role 
        from
            users u1_0 
        where
            u1_0.login_id=?
    2024-02-26T15:01:04.330+09:00  INFO 60005 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] TestController                           : test controller
```

From the logs, I was able to confirm that the test controller is being called. However, the page does not load, and only the HTML code is displayed in the message.

**Developer Tools Message**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBXBE.png)

**Test.html**

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"
>             integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g="
> crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>     <title>Test Page</title> </head> <body> <h1>This is a test page.</h1> </body> </html>
```

**Summary**

1. After a successful login, you're redirected to the index page.
2. From this index page, the goal is to navigate to the test page.
3. I've confirmed that the authorization filter processes the request and the token value is passed along.
4. The request reaches the test controller, but the actual page fails to load.

What could I possibly be missing?  I've been wracking my brain over this for days,,, please help me,,,

Comment: You are using javascript soyou need to replace the content yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to understand the difference between an **AJAX** request and a normal request:

- With a normal request, the browser will make the request and load the
  response onto the screen. This is what you desire.
- However here, you're sending an AJAX request by using $.ajax() method. With
  AJAX request, the browser will let you handle the response yourself.

As far as I know, the only way to make browser treat a request as normal request is submit it via a HTML form. But in your case, I see that you need to use $.ajax() to add token to 'Authorization' header, then you have to display the response yourself